# Jekyll Slideshow Side-By-Side With Regular Posts

Tags: jekyll

I am looking to make a slideshow using Jekyll but would like to have the slideshow be a single post alongside regular blog posts. I found a few Jekyll themed slideshows using impress.js [here](https://github.com/bmcmurray/hekyll) and [here](https://github.com/bcaccinolo/jekyll-impressjs-plugin), but in the examples for both they are relying on a single static html file that simply pulls all of the posts from the _posts folder. I can filter out the non-slideshow posts by class, but that would not solve the situation of having two slideshows as slides from both would be pulled in.

Is there a way of passing information from the slide post (eg a "Title") that can be read in the static html file to determine which posts belong to this slideshow? Alternatively, is there a different way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I have been diggin into it anyway

[Hekyll](https://github.com/bmcmurray/hekyll) is a very nice tool
To prevent a post from showing up in a presentation, you can mark it with a specific tag in the front matter, say `not_a_slide: true`

Then edit the layout `perso.html` [here at the root of the project](https://github.com/lexoyo/hekyll/blob/gh-pages/preso.html) and `{% unless page.not_a_slide %}` before `{% include slide.html %}` and `{% endunless %}` after.